# How does delete deal with pointer constness?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I was reading this question [Deleting a const pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755196/deleting-a-const-pointer) and wanted to know more about `delete` behavior. Now, as per my understanding:

`delete expression` works in two steps:

1. invoke destructor
2. then releases the memory (often with a call to `free()`) by calling operator delete.

`operator delete` accepts a `void*`. As part of a test program I overloaded `operator delete` and found that `operator delete` doesn't accept `const` pointer.

Since operator delete does not accept const pointer and delete internally calls operator delete, how does [Deleting a const pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755196/deleting-a-const-pointer) work ?

Does `delete` uses const_cast internally?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

const_cast doesn't really do anything – it's a way to suppress compiler moaning about const-ness of the object. *delete* keyword is a compiler construct, the compiler knows what to do in this case and doesn't care about const-ness of the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755196/deleting-a-const-pointer/755224#755224) says, `delete` is not a method like any other, but a part of the langage to destruct objects. `const`-ness has no bearing on destructability.

Answer (score 3):

> operator delete accepts a void*. As part of a test program I overloaded operator delete and found that operator delete doesn't accept const pointer.

How did you try this? It certainly **does** accept const pointers:

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    void* const px = 0;
    delete px;
    ::operator delete(px);
}
```

This code is correct, compiles (albeit with a justified warning) and executes.

**EDIT**: Reading the original article – you aren't talking about a const pointer but *a pointer to `const`*, which is something else. The reason why this has to work is described there. As for why it's working: others have said this.

Answer (score 1):

`delete` is an operator that you can overload. It takes a pointer as an argument, and frees the memory, possibly using `free`. The compiler allows this whether the pointer is `const` or not.

Comment: This isn't actually correct. A fine but important distinction has to be drawn between the operator `delete` (cannot be changed) and the function `operator delete` (which can be). The former calls the latter but they are *not* identical.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, yes, that's true, but it doesn't make that much of a difference.

Answer (score -1):

`delete` just makes a call to deallocate the memory the pointer points to, it doesn't change the value of the pointer nor the object. Therefore, `delete` has nothing to do with the `const`-ness of the pointer or object pointed to.