# NULL check before deleting an object with an overloaded delete

Tags: c++, null, delete-operator

This came up as one of the code review comments.

Is it a good idea to check for NULL before calling delete for any object?

I do understand delete operator checks for NULL internally and is redundant but the argument put forth was delete as an operator can be overloaded and if the overloaded version doesn't check for the NULL it may crash. So is it safe and reasonable to assume that if and when delete will be overloaded it will check for the NULL or not? 
In my understanding its reasonable to assume the first case that overloaded delete shall take care of the NULL check, and the review point doesn't hold good. What do you think?

Comment: Hah. Apparently nobody (me included) read the question fully before answering.

Comment: @Konrad - :) Tells us how eager people are to help out.This is great site. Love it!

Comment: see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265666/reason-why-not-to-have-a-delete-macro-for-c

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, don't check for null. The standard says that `delete (T*)0;` is valid. It will just complicate your code for no benefits. If `operator delete` is overloaded it's better to check for null in the implementation of the operator. Just saves code lines and bugs.

**EDIT:** This answer was accepted and upvoted, yet, in my opinion, it was not very informative. There is one missing piece in all answers here, and, for conscience sake, let me add this last piece here.

The standard actually says in [basic.stc.dynamic], at least since C++03:

> Any allocation and/or deallocation functions defined in a C++ program, including the default versions in the library, shall conform to the semantics specified in 3.7.4.1 and 3.7.4.2.

Where the referenced sections, as well as some other places in the standard listed in other answers, say that the semantics of passing a null pointer are a no-op.

Comment: so does it mean incase of overloaded `operator delete` the responsibilty of conforming with the standard lies in the implementation of the operator ? i.e. if it doesn't check for NULL then it is not conforming to the standard?

Comment: @Naveen - That is the question I am trying get an answer to, Thanks for bringing it out with right words!

Comment: @Naveen @Als: Yes in weak sense. No in the strong sense of the word "conforming". If you implement operator delete that doesn't check for NULL it's still conforming (e.g. it just prints `cout << address << '\n'`). But if it brings undefined behavior it's a bug in your `operator delete` implementation.

Comment: @ybungalobill: It is non conforming in all senses. A conforming implementation of `delete` must be able to handle 0 as an argument. There is no way to consider something to be *conforming* if for a well defined operation it yields undefined behavior. Conformance is not only at the interface level, it is not just that the arguments match, but the semantics must be the same.

Comment: @David: Please read ybungalobill's comment fully---it _can_ be conforming if it doesn't invoke UB. For example: placement `delete` doesn't do anything with its argument (at all), so, it doesn't need to check for null either.

Comment: @David @Chris Sorry, what I said is actually partially nonsense. What I answered was the question stated as "if it doesn't check for NULL then it is not conforming". Well it can be conforming without checking for null.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: *placement delete*??

Comment: @David: So, with custom `new` operators, you can (and should) define corresponding custom `delete` operators, so that if the construction of the object fails, the allocated memory can be deallocated. Placement `delete` corresponds to placement `new` (which, of course, also does nothing except return the given pointer).

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: To quote the standard in 18.4.1.3 **Placement forms**: *"These functions are reserved, a C++ program may not define functions that displace the versions in the Standard C++ library (17.4.3). The provisions of (3.7.3) do not apply to these reserved placement forms of operator new and operator delete."* That is, you cannot *displace* (override/replace) the placement forms, and that means that you cannot possibly provide a *conforming* implementation that does not check null (nor one that does check).

Comment: @David: Right, I wasn't suggesting to make a placement `delete` yourself, but using it as a counterexample for the "must check null or is non-conformant" statement.

Comment: The thing is that there are different things that are all called `new`/`delete`, and the only one that you can *displace* is the allocator version of it. In that case, the user provided `delete` must be able to handle 0 as argument (note that as in the initial comment I am not saying *check for 0*, but that it must be able to handle that value passed as argument).

Comment: @David: as @ybungalobill stated, checking for NULL isn't required not to trigger UB. Therefore checking for NULL is not required to be conforming, all that is required is that it works with NULL.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I agree, either I misunderstood or I have failed to be clear in my writing. Caller does not need nor should check for null. User implementation of `delete` must be able to handle `0` properly without triggering UB to be conforming.

Comment: @ybungalobill hm, I read the  referenced sections ([basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation] to be exact) and it states "The value of the first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, `and if the deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library`, the call has no effect.", i.e. doesn't that mean that `noop` behaviour is only required from std delete, not from user-defined?

Answer (score 19):

I would say that that's more a reason to ensure that if you overload `operator delete`, then you should always have it check for `NULL`, otherwise you're breaking the semantics.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it a good idea to check for NULL before calling delete for any object?

No!

```
int *p = NULL;
delete p ; //no effect
```

The Standard says [Section 5.3.5/2]

> If the operand has a class type, the operand is converted to a pointer type by calling the above-mentioned conversion function, and the converted operand is used in place of the original operand for the remainder of this section.  In either alternative, **if the value of the operand of delete is the null pointer the operation has no effect**.

Furthermore in Section `18.4.1.1/13`

`void operator delete(void* ptr) throw();`

`void operator delete(void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) throw();`

> Default behavior:
>
> —  **For a null value of ptr, do nothing**.
>
> —  Any  other  value  of ptr shall  be  a  value  returned  earlier  by  a  call  to  the  default operator new, which  was  not  invalidated  by  an  intervening  call  to operator delete(void*) (17.4.3.7).  For such a non-null value of ptr, reclaims storage allocated by the earlier call to the default operator new.

**EDIT** :

James Kanze [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/853692-null-pointer-overloaded-operator-delete) says that

> It's still the responisiblity of operator delete (or delete[]) to check; the standard doesn't guarantee that it won't be given a null pointer; the standard requires that it be a no-op if given a null pointer. Or that the implementation is allowed to call it. According to the latest draft, "The value of the first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library, the call has no effect." I'm not quite sure what the implications of that "is one supplied in the standard library" are meant to be---taken literally, since his function is not one provided by the standard library, the sentence wouldn't seem to apply. But somehow, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @wilhelmtell : Can't you see a big **NO**?

Comment: I can, but your reasoning obviously shows you stopped reading at the question's title. The OP *KNOWS* this is a noop in the default case.

Comment: @wihelmtell : No I didn't stop after reading the question's title. That's why I have linked the `bytes.com` thread and asked him to read James Kanze's answer.

Answer (score 6):

I would say it is the responsibility of an overloaded `delete` to behave like you expect `delete` to behave. That is, it *should* handle NULL pointers as a no-op.

And so, when calling an overloaded delete, you should *not* check for NULL. You should rely on the overloaded delete to be implemented correctly.

Answer (score 3):

No need to check null.  delete operator does chck for null so additional check is not required.

Answer (score 3):

`delete (T*)0;` is valid and does nothing, similarly `free(NULL);` is also valid and does nothing. If you overload the `delete` operator, your implementation should carry the same semantics. The standard says how the standard `delete` will work, but I don't think it says how an overloaded `delete` should behave. For the sake of consistency with the standard/default behaviour, it should allow `(T*)0` as input.

Answer (score 3):

From Standard docs, *18.5.1.1.13* under `delete`,

> Default behavior: **If ptr is null, does nothing.** Otherwise, reclaims the storage allocated by the earlier call to
>   operator new.

So, you don't have to check *by default*..

Answer (score 2):

No need to check for NULL prior to deleting. If someone has overloading `delete` with something that does not behave in a standard way then *that's* the real problem. No-one should take lightly the task of overloading `delete` and should always support expected behaviour such as checking for NULL and taking no action.

However, for what it's worth, you should *always* remember to assign zero to any pointer that you've just deleted, unless for example you are about to delete the pointer as well:

```
void MyObj::reset()
{
    delete impl_;
    impl_ = 0;    // Needed here - impl_ may be reused / referenced.
}

MyObj::~MyObj()
{
    delete impl_; // No need to assign here as impl_ is going out of scope.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it **not** necesary to check. If anyone overload the pethod, is his responsibility to to whatever with NULL.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the questions contains incomplete information. My shop still has a check for NULL before delete in our coding standard, as we still have one compiler/platform configuration that we must support that goes into undefined behavior with the defualt delete operator if it is passed NULL. If the original poster has a simular situation then there is a point to the check for NULL, otherwise, change the coding standard!

Comment: Sorry, No my platform does not have any such limitation, but assuming one always write a portable code delete implementation will have to be overloaded most of the times(memory leak detection based logging, special memory implementations etc) so the question still holds good doesnt it?

Comment: @Als The compiler/platform configuration will go into undefinded behaviour for even built-in types (i.e. int, char, etc) as it really is a bug with the platforms free() implementation, but there have been no fixes for it as it is a dead platform.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of C++ pedantry:
NULL is not a built-in concept.  Yes we all know what it means but in C++ before C++0X the null pointer concept is simply the value 0.  NULL is usually a platform-specific macro that expands to 0.

With C++0X we're getting nullptr which is clearer than a plain zero and is not convertible to any integral type except bool, and is a better concept than NULL (or perhaps a better implementation of the concept behind NULL).

Comment: Alternatively, a lot of C++ pedantry: a null pointer is the value "a null pointer", not (necessarily) the value 0, which is an integer, not a pointer. When converted to a pointer type, a *constant* integer expression with value 0 results in a null pointer (and hence is called a "null pointer constant"), but that's a special case defined in the standard.

Comment: Well since the only way to define a null pointer through the language prior to C++0X is to use the constant value literal 0 and that results in calling the integer overload rather than the pointer overload, that is REALLY pedantic ,-)

Comment: There are other ways to get a null pointer. For example, `std::strstr("a","b");`. Obviously, using a null pointer constant is the *sensible* way. My bonus pedantry is just to point out that there's a difference between `0` (an integer, and a null pointer constant, and a possible value for NULL) vs `(char*)0` or `(void*)0` (both null pointers, and both null pointer constants, but neither is legal for NULL in C++).