# Why is "operator delete" invoked when I call "delete" on a null pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

While reading answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821261/null-check-before-deleting-an-object) I noticed that answers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821261/null-check-before-deleting-an-object/3821277#3821277) for example) imply that `operator delete` can be called even when `delete` statement is executed on a null pointer.

So I wrote a small snippet:

```
class Test {
public:
    void* operator new( size_t ) { /*doesn't matter*/ return 0; }
    void operator delete( void* ptr ) {
        ptr; //to suppress warning and have a line to put breakpoint on
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test* ptr = 0;
    delete ptr;
}
```

and - surprisingly for me - `Test::operator delete()` is invoked with `ptr` holding a null pointer.

As I understand it `operator new` allocates memory and `operator delete` returns memory to the allocator. If I call `delete` statement on a null pointer it means there was no object behind the pointer and there's no memory to return to the allocator.

`delete` statement includes invoking a destructor. When I pass a null pointer the destructor is surely not invoked - C++ takes care of that. Then why is `operator delete` invoked in this case?

Comment: Ask also why `operator new` is invoked when you allocate zero length array: `new Test[0];`... ;)

Comment: @ybungalobill: That's easier - the Standard requires the returned pointer to be valid and distinct.

Comment: Note that if you make the destructor virtual, the overload `operator delete` will not be called. Implementations usually invoke the function directly from the destructor and call the destructor without a check for null (thus saving a few instructions). Only when the call needs virtual dispatch is the check performed in advance.

Comment: One more thing: invoking the operator from the destructor is convenient, because it saves one virtual dispatch.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The language in the upcoming C++0x standard (section 5.3.5 `[expr.delete]`) is as follows:

> If the value of the operand of
>   the delete-expression is not a null
>   pointer value, the delete-expression
>   will call a  deallocation function
>   (3.7.4.2). Otherwise, it is
>   unspecified whether the deallocation
>   function will be called. [ Note: The
>   deallocation function is called
>   regardless of whether the destructor
>   for the object or some element of the
>   array throws an exception.  — end note ]

So it is unspecified behavior, some compilers may call `operator delete` when a NULL pointer is deleted and others may not.

EDIT: The term *deallocation function* used by the standard seems to be causing some confusion.  It comes with a reference.  Some key language from 3.7.4.2 `[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]` which may help clarify:

> If a class `T` has a member deallocation function named `operator delete`
>   with exactly one parameter, then that function is a usual (non-placement) deallocation function.

The standard is also very clear that user-defined `operator delete` needs to accept a parameter which is a null pointer value:

> The value of the
>   first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation
>   function  is  one  supplied  in  the  standard  library,  the  call  has  no  effect.

But because of the unspecified behavior 5.3.5, you shouldn't rely on your `operator delete` being called when the pointer is null.

Comment: Hmm, this snippet is talking about the deallocation function, not the operator.

Comment: C++03 seems to be vague on the issue. It says "if the value of the operand of delete is the null pointer the operation
has no effect", then, "If the delete-expression calls
the implementation deallocation function...", then, "The delete-expression will call a deallocation function". So either it must not call the overloaded operator, or it's unspecified, or it must call it. One of the three ;-)

Comment: @Hans: deallocation function is the function implementing `operator delete`. This terminology comes from the fact that operators appear in expressions, while function that implement them *are* function. In other words you need to separate somehow your terminology.

Answer (score 9):

Operator delete is just like any other operator, why wouldn't it be invoked? It can't examine its arguments *before* being invoked.

This is like asking why `operator+` is invoked when you're adding 0.

Comment: The `delete` statement doesn't just call `operator delete`, it first calls the destructor, and a null check is necessarily done before calling the destructor (and hence before calling `operator delete`).  `operator delete` is not like other operator overloads.

Comment: Okay, but there's no way for the compiler to be sure that a user-defined operator delete is a no-op when given a null pointer. It could, for example, log something indicating that you attempted to delete a null pointer.

Comment: Agree with Ben Voigt: when you type `delete p;`, the compiler first calls the destructor of the object and then the deallocation function `operator delete`. The system must be able to diagnose that the pointer is 0 as to avoid calling the destructor (which it won't call), so technically it could also avoid calling the deallocator.

Comment: Actually, the C++ standard explicitly allows the compiler to avoid calling `operator delete` with a null pointer value.