# How to replace delete and delete []

Tags: c++

I want to replace `delete` and `delete[]` with `_delete ptr`;
I need it because `delete` method doesn't set ptr to NULL. For example now I'm using this code for memory clean up:

```
#define _delete( ptr )    { delete ptr; ptr = NULL; }
#define _deleteA( ptr )   { delete [] ptr; ptr = NULL; }

MyClass *cls = new MyClass();
int *value = new int value[100];
....
_delete(cls);
_deleteA(value);
```

But I want to use my function like:

```
_delete cls;
_delete value;
```

Is it possable?

Or if not how to replace it with:

```
_delete cls;
_delete[] value;
```

Comment: `class` is a keyword in C++.

Comment: I doubt that's valid syntax

Comment: No, it's not possable. Neither of them is.

Comment: It's also a rather pointless exercise, as it solves only a tiny subset of pointer-related problems, and only the easy ones at that. Consider what happens when you have several pointers to the same memory.

Comment: Use vectors and smart pointers and you don't have to write delete ever again.

Comment: @Neil [Is it good practice to NULL a pointer after deleting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931126/is-it-good-practice-to-null-a-pointer-after-deleting-it) contains all around good advice that says "**don't do this**", but I'm not sure if it's a duplicate.

Comment: Consider that an invalid pointer could not be NULL; it could point to anywhere in the processor's address space, especially where there is no memory allocated.

Comment: Pointers should be deleted in destructors. There's no point setting the pointer to NULL in a destructor, as the pointer immediately ceases to exist, so it also ceases to be NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a good idea. Macros are not the proper tool for the job. Aside from the fact that it probably isn't possible, it will be confusing to anyone maintaining your code. There are several superior alternatives.

If you have C++11, you should prefer to use smart pointers such as [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) whenever possible. [MatthiasB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869669/how-to-replace-delete-and-delete/26869960#comment42298675_26869960) also makes a valid point that you should opt to take advantage of the standard library and use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of dynamically allocated arrays.

Otherwise, you can take advantage of tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [LLVM's AddressSanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#usage). It's available in Clang and has been ported to GCC 4.9. To use it, specify `-fsanitize=address` at the command line.

If you insist on textual replacement, a manual search-and-replace in your favorite IDE might do the trick. I wouldn't recommend it though.

A discussion in [Is it good practice to NULL a pointer after deleting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931126/is-it-good-practice-to-null-a-pointer-after-deleting-it) reveals that this practice is indicative of possible design problems in your program. For example, [jalf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931145/3920237):

> Setting pointers to NULL after you've deleted what it pointed to
>   certainly can't hurt, but it's often a bit of a band-aid over a more
>   fundamental problem: Why are you using a pointer in the first place? I
>   can see two typical reasons:
>
> - You simply wanted something allocated on the heap. In which case wrapping it in a RAII object would have been much safer and cleaner.
>     End the RAII object's scope when you no longer need the object. That's
>     how `std::vector` works, and it solves the problem of accidentally
>     leaving pointers to deallocated memory around. There are no pointers.
> - Or perhaps you wanted some complex shared ownership semantics. The pointer returned from `new` might not be the same as the one that
>     `delete` is called on. Multiple objects may have used the object
>     simultaneously in the meantime. In that case, a shared pointer or
>     something similar would have been preferable.
>
> My rule of thumb is that if you leave pointers around in user code,
>   you're Doing It Wrong. The pointer shouldn't be there to point to
>   garbage in the first place. Why isn't there an object taking
>   responsibility for ensuring its validity? Why doesn't its scope end
>   when the pointed-to object does?

Comment: not to forget `std::vector` for dynamic arrays instead of direct pointer allocation wherever applicable.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possibe. However, you can look at the answer posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265666/reason-why-not-to-have-a-delete-macro-for-c) that might be useful.

Comment: Read it, just was interesting is it possable to replace or rewrite this methods somehow