# Can a destructor call a non-const function on a const object?

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, destructor

I searched for the answer to this question and wasn't able to find one. Consider the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    int *bar;
    Foo(int barValue) : bar(new int(barValue)) {}
    ~Foo() { do_this(); }
    void do_this() { delete bar; bar = nullptr; }
};

int main()
{
    const Foo foo(7);
}
```

`do_this()` cannot be called on a `const` object, so I couldn't do something like `foo.do_this()`. It would also make sense in some situations to call `do_this()` outside of the destructor, which is why I don't want to simply include the code in the destructor definition. Because `do_this()` modifies a member variable, I can't declare it as `const`.

My question is: will the destructor be able to call `do_this()` on a `const` object when the object is destroyed?

I tried it and received no errors, but I want to make sure I'm not causing a memory leak once my program terminates.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8372475/7359094).

Comment: You pretty much *have* to be able to modify the object in the destructor in order to free up resources. Whether that happens directly in the destructor or in some other function doesn't matter.

Comment: "... causing a memory leak once my program terminates..." Makes no sense. Once the program *terminates* all resources it allocated are freed by the kernel - leaks are no longer a concern. Leaks *are* a concern when they happen while the program is running, since you may then run out of resources. But after termination, worrying about leaks is void.

Comment: but mutating `const` object is UB...

Comment: @Jarod42: While it is `const`, yes. That's a rather relevant limitation. It's also why the constructor and destructor are `special functions`.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl  True, thanks.

Comment: @JesperJuhl this is strictly true, but with SBRM (or RAI) we should not care about memory leak that much as we care about unfreed resources in general. And some of those can certainly outlive the application. Because of that, I think the question is valid, even is in a broader scope.

Comment: @SergeyA Sure, for *non*-memory resources, running destructors may be important. But, the question *specifically* said "memory leaks".

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know. I just believe that by slightly expanding the definition we can get some benefits :) Also, in the nitpicking mode, nothing in the question actually tells us that OP is using a kernel, may be it is an embedded device where memory is not managed by outside entity?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly and safely call non-const functions from destructor. Standard explicitly allows this:

> 15.4/2 A destructor is used to destroy objects of its class type. The address
>   of a destructor shall not be taken. A destructor can be invoked for a
>   const, volatile or const volatile object. const and volatile semantics
>   ([dcl.type.cv]) are not applied on an object under destruction. They
>   stop being in effect when the destructor for the most derived object
>   starts.