# How do you correctly initialize a struct with a member that is a const pointer to a const value?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, constants

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
struct foo
{
    const int
        *const a,
        *const b, 
        *const c;

    foo(int a, int b, int c)
            : a(_a), b(_b), c(_c)
    {
        *_a = a;
        *_b = b;
        *_c = c;
    }

private:
    int _a[1], _b[1], _c[1];

};
```

but is there a way to do this without putting in the second set of pointers (`_a, _b, _c`)?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JerryCoffin learn C++ language syntax...

Comment: Let me rephrase. You say: "...is there a way to do this without ..." The question is what "this" do you want to do? Right now, I can't make enough sense of your code to figure out what the code should do.

Comment: @JerryCoffin probably a bit confusing because of scope... basically the question is how to create a new pointer to an int without declaring `int *ptr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but is there a way to do this without putting in the second set of pointers (`_a`, `_b`, `_c`)?

Sure. You can use:

```
foo(int a, int b, int c)
        : a(new int(a)), b(new int(b)), c(new int(c)) {}
```

Keep in mind [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and implement copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor appropriately for `foo`.

Comment: The destructor for this will likely be considerably more entertaining.

Comment: @Praetorian, my understanding is that he wants to obviate the need for `_a`, `_b`, and `_c`.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes, it will :)

Comment: @RSahu you're right. Solved my problem and helped me understand how the `new` operator works in C++. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephNields consider it an exercise off-site to figure out how to properly `delete` those.

Comment: @RSahu I'll be damned, you managed to figure out the intent! I was thinking the OP was looking for something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93a2e6dc93ff6a11) But the obvious solution in this case is for `a,b,c` to be `(const) int` instead of pointers.

Comment: @Praetorian, that might be the real solution after the OP tries to figure out how to delete the objects.

Comment: @WhozCraig what's wrong with just `~foo() {delete a, b, c;}` ?

Comment: @JosephNields, the compiler won't let you call `delete` on a pointer that points to a `const` object.

Comment: @RSahu why does that line compile then?

Comment: @JosephNields, I am surprised too. I thought that violated the `const`-ness of the object but maybe not. After all, destructors have to called even for `const` objects when they get out out scope. BTW, that should be `{delete a; delete b; delete c;}`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the reason `delete` on a `const` pointer works, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2271055/241631). @JosephNields `~foo() {delete a, b, c;}` is very wrong. You've only deleted `a`, and leaked `b` and `c`. Read up on the comma operator.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. All this time I never bothered trying to fire `delete` on a const pointer. (probably because I never had a need to, i guess. gotta learn something every day.=P)

Comment: Exception safety goes out of the window, of course. If a later `new` throws, there's literally no way to release the memory previously allocated.

Comment: That was an entertaining read. I could have bet that you cannot do `delete const T* const`