# Should allocator::get_deleter() be const qualified?

Tags: c++, constants, api-design, allocator

I'm trying to provide a `get_deleter()` for my lock-free allocator class template (code is [here](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/lock_free/blob/4780047e27e5a008fcb435f77a8702f1ed14ced7/lf/allocator.hpp)). The deleter is something like

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct deleter {
  allocator<T>& alloc;
  void operator()(T* p) const noexcept {
    p->~T();
    alloc.deallocate(p);
  }
};
```

Note that `alloc` should not be `const`, since `deallocate()` is not `const`, which aligns with [`std::allocator::deallocate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/deallocate). Now, I'm not sure whether my `allocator::get_deleter()` should be `const`. The dilemma is as follows:

**1. Rationale for being `const`:** The method itself doesn't modify `*this`, and is thread-safe (also see [Does const mean thread-safe in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127379/does-const-mean-thread-safe-in-c11)).

**2. Rationale for not being `const`:** The method returns a `deleter` that can be used to modify `*this`. Also avoids `const_cast()` that is necessary if the method is `const`.

Any suggestion or idea? Personally, I'm in favor of `const`.

Comment: I would personally favor the intent and not mark it as `const` if marking it as `const` would mean I can delete a const object without getting any warning. Doesn't sound like something I want to allow. Perhaps provide both?

Comment: @spectras But you can call the destructor of a `const` object, right? Yet, `operator delete()` doesn't accept `const` pointer. What a dilemma :(

Comment: That's an explicit exception: *“A destructor can be invoked for a const, volatile or const volatile object. [...] const and volatile semantics are not applied on an object under destruction”*. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2271055/3212865

Comment: @spectras Then I think this exception should also apply to deallocation, otherwise the memory of `const` objects could not be reclaimed. The `deleter` does just these two things: destroy and deallocate.

Comment: I understand your point. It's true one can delete a const object. And in fact your deleter is running the destructor so the same argument used to justify destruction exception could indeed apply.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't `const_cast<allocator &>(*this)`

You don't know if anyone is going to have a `const allocator<...>` value and get undefined behaviour. Even if you don't, you are lying about how `const` it really is.

`allocator::get_deleter` *can't* be `const` without a `const_cast`, so it *shouldn't*.

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5f9289df0e6e31f)

Comment: This has already been discussed in the question as a pro for non-const.

Comment: Edited to be more specific. Just because `const_cast` exists, doesn't mean you should use it