# How can we call "delete this; " in a const-member function?

Tags: c++, delete-operator, const-correctness

I saw the code snippet as follows:

```
class UPNumber {
public:
  UPNumber();
  UPNumber(int initValue);
  ...

  // pseudo-destructor (a const member function, because
  // even const objects may be destroyed)
  void destroy() const { delete this; } // why this line is correct???

  ...

private:
  ~UPNumber();
};
```

First, I am sure that above class definition is correct.
Here is my question, why we can define the function 'destroy' as above?
The reason being asking is that why we can modify 'this' in a const-member function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `const` qualifier applied to a method have the effect of making the `this` passed to it a `const` pointer; in particular, in your case it will be a `const UPNumber *`.

Still, this is not a problem for `delete`: actually you can use `delete` on a `const` pointer without having to cast anything, as specified at §5.3.5 ¶2:

> [Note: a pointer to a const type can be the operand of a delete-expression; it is not necessary to cast away the constness (5.2.11) of the pointer expression before it is used as the operand of the delete-expression. ]

Notice that, before the standard was completed, there have been many discussion about whether this was or wasn't a good idea, so some pre-standard compilers will issue an error when trying to `delete` `const` pointers.

The idea behind allowing this behavior is that otherwise you would have no way to `delete` `const` objects without using a `const_cast`; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755196/deleting-a-const-pointer) for more info.

Answer (score 13):

That works for the same reason that this work:

```
const int* upn = new int();
delete upn;
```

You can `delete` a pointer to a const-qualified object.  The const-qualification on the member function just means that `this` has a type `const UPNumber*`.

Comment: @James, here, we cannot call "delete upn" b/c the destructor is private. -- thx

Comment: @q0987: Class members have access to private members. The function `destroy` requires access to the destructor, because of the `delete this` expression, and has access because it's a member of the class.

Comment: @GMan:  I think the OP was complaining about my example, which at first used his `UPNumber` class instead of `int`.

Comment: @James: When reading your code I thought you were trying to make a reference to the old UPN network. :)

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get the idea that we are modifying `this`? In fact, `this` is not an lvalue. It It cannot ever be modified, regardless of whether the member function is `const` or not.

Applying *delete-expression* to a pointer (any pointer, not just `this`) is not in any way considered a modification of that pointer. Moreover, the argument of delete-expression is treated as rvalue, meaning that it cannot possibly be modified by `delete`.

So, there are no problems with that application of `delete` in your code.

Comment: if I understood your point right, the const-member function ONLY promises NOT change the values pointed by this. --thx

Comment: I think this is more than needs to be said about the fact that the questioner has mistakenly written "why we can modify 'this' in a const-member function?", despite meaning something more like, "why can we modify the object *through* `this`". The unspoken assumption being that deleting an object is a form of modification (and really it is, since the destructor is free to modify members on its way out).

Answer (score 0):

As it is **technically possible and defined** to call `delete this` [provided that you are careful](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html), the constness of the "suicide" method is **technically pointless**, since the object must not be touched after the call.

That's why it is **semantically incorrect** to have a `const` method calling `delete this`.

An interesting point brought [Steve Jessep's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148656/c-how-can-we-call-delete-this-in-a-const-member-function/27801064#comment5779757_5148782). Running the destructor doesn't keep an object unchanged, so applying the concept of *const*ness is questionable.