# Why a "const T*" is trivially converted to "void*" in "operator delete"?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, free, delete-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting a pointer to const (T const*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755196/deleting-a-pointer-to-const-t-const)

```
void operator delete (void*);
...
const char *pn = new char, *pm = (char*)malloc(1);
delete pn; // allowed !!
free(pm); // error
```

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/IPX25).

It's understandable that `free()` is a function, so a `const void*` cannot be converted to `void*`. But why is it allowed in the case of `operator delete` (default or overloaded) ?

Is it not functionally a wrong construct ?

Comment: deleting a `void*` is UB anyway, so who cares?

Comment: It's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755196/deleting-a-pointer-to-const-t-const

Comment: @tenfour, well `const T*` should first converted to `T*` and then it's converted to `void*`. So it should not be UB. Otherwise all `delete`s are UB.

Comment: oops, of course. I didn't read the code closely enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I quite agree with @JamesKanze's answer, perhaps somebody would like to see what the standard actually says. According to the standard (§12.1/4):

> const and volatile semantics (7.1.5.1) are not applied on an object under
>   construction. Such semantics only come into effect once the constructor for the most derived object (1.8)
>   ends.

and (§12.4/2):

> const and
>   volatile semantics (7.1.5.1) are not applied on an object under destruction. Such semantics stop being
>   into effect once the destructor for the most derived object (1.8) starts.

In fairness, this does little more than re-state what @James said, a bit more specifically: the object is only really considered an object from the time the ctor finishes (or *all* the ctors, when inheritance is involved) to the point that the first dtor begins. Outside those boundaries, const and volatile aren't enforced.

Comment: There's a subtle difference. James says, "*After* destruction, you are left with a `void*`. " Standard says, "Such semantics stop being into effect once the destructor for the most derived object (1.8) starts." So, from what James said, someone could *infer* that `const` semantics were still in effect during destructor execution, and be wrong. It's really nitpicking, though.

Answer (score 4):

It's not.  The `delete` expression first calls the destructor.  *After*
destruction, you are left with a `void*`.  (The typical implementation,
in fact, has the destructor call the `operator delete()` function, since
which `operator delete()` to call depends on the most derived class.)

As to why your `T const*` becomes a `T*` in the destructor: is this any 
different than:

```
{
    T const anObject;
    //  ...
} // destructor of anObject called here.  With T*, not T const*
```

?  One can argue for different rules, but in the end, destructors are
special, and obey special rules.

Comment: In other words, destruction casts away `const`.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: I see it another way. `const` only applies to living objects. Constructors and Destructors are executed outside this life period, so it does not apply to them.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Or ignores it.  Destructors and constructors play games with type anyway, so what's one more anomaly?