# Why there is no std::free overload for const void*?

Tags: c++, std

I use an extern C function that returns dynamically allocated `const char*`.

I want to use `unique_ptr<const char, decltype(std::free)>` to manage it.

But there is no `std::free(const void*)` overload so I get `invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*'` and have to use `const_cast<char*>()`.

Is this just a Standard Library imperfection or there is something else behind it?

Comment: @ForceBru, the pointer is not `const`, it points to `const` memory.

Comment: @ForceBru: Yet it's ok to [`delete` `const` pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/755196/10077).

Comment: @FredLarson, didn't know that, thanks for the info!

Comment: If the function is giving back something you're supposed to `free`, it shouldn't be a pointer-to-const. `free` is well within its rights to modify the memory it frees AFAIK. This is a problem with the function, not `free`. I don't know of any case where dynamically allocated memory would be unmodifiable (and this is the part where someone points out a little-known system).

Comment: Note that `const T*` is not always a pointer to a `const T`. It can also mean a "`const` view" on a mutable `T`.
When you allocate memory with `malloc`, the returned memory is always considered mutable (or else, you couldn't do anything with it). This means that it is always safe to `const_cast` away your `const T*` if you intend to `free` it (since it implies it was allocated with `malloc`, or else it's UB).

Comment: @chris I already used that pattern in cases where I store a pointer to a c style string and nobody shall be able to modify that string. Only one central function was sometimes free-ing the memory and strdup-ing a new string value. For external clients of the class I could separate implementation and getter. But I also wanted to have const as some simple protection for inside the class. If you have a better pattern for that, I'ld like to hear it.

Comment: @chris, nevertheless, I am allowed to do this `delete[] new const char[2]{'t', 0};`

Comment: @WernerHenze, In general, if I have a resource, I like its lifetime management to be contained within a single class, and the class ideally doesn't do much else. For memory, that means it can store it non-const and it or whatever uses it can expose the memory as const all it likes, the class responsible for deallocating it knows it's not const without a cast or anything. For a string, it's entirely possible to have a class that exposes a `std::string_view` for its internal memory, and that's all it does, where the real class uses only the view for protection.

Comment: @sad1raf, I can at least see where freeing a pointer-to-const would be useful if the external function initializes the data and allows no further modification beyond that. However, it's still a poor decision because it requires a cast in order to free it. If doing this, the library should have a specific function available to safely free these strings without ugly casts. As for `delete`, I could entirely see the `const` here being a view to initialized data that shouldn't change, yet backed by mutable memory. In that case, destruction through `const` works fine and deallocation could zero etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::free` is inherited from the C standard library. C does not have overloading, so a `const` overload could not have been inherited.

While the C++ standard library has extended the inherited C library with some useful overloads, a `const` overload has not been added for `free`.

Either such an overload has never been considered, or it has not been considered necessary enough to warrant its addition to the standard. I have not come across any openly available proposal for such an addition -- although I haven't read all proposals there have ever been, nor have I attended any committee meetings or workshops, so  I cannot deny the possibility of the existence of such a document.

To work around the lack of such an overload, you can indeed use `const_cast`. In this context, it is completely safe.

Comment: This would not require an overload. A single function taking `const void *` would work in both C and C++.

Comment: @hvd Sure. But has the C++ standard changed any of the function signatures of C library functions? Would the committee even consider such option? I wouldn't assume so, but perhaps. Perhaps the C library will be changed, but I find it unlikely to be a priority for them considering implicit const T* -> T* conversion is legal in C.

Comment: Yes, the C++ standard has changed function signatures of C library functions (see `strchr`), but no, that isn't what I meant. *If* the C committee were to declare that `free(const void *)` makes sense and adjusted its signature accordingly, C++ could adopt that. And no, standard C does not have an implicit `const T *` -> `T *` conversion, and never has. C compilers are free to support it as an extension. C++ compilers are also allowed to support it as an extension, it's just that it's more difficult to do it correctly in C++ as it might break SFINAE uses, that's why C++ compilers usually don't

Comment: @hvd thanks for correcting me on the implicit conversion. I'm glad to be wrong about that.