# How does C++ compiler work when compiling `operator delete`?

Tags: c++, compilation

I notice that the declaration of  `delete` in the directory of gcc source `gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new`is

```
    void operator delete(void*)
    void operator delete[](void*)
```

Why can we pass `const ptr` to the operator?

```
    const int* a = new int(1);
    delete(a);
```

I think `void*` and `const int*` are incompatible types.

Comment: Note the difference between [`delete` _expression_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) and [`operator delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

Comment: Construction/destruction isn't const restricted. Consider `const Foo foo;`, where `Foo` is an object class type. The result is a `foo` where you can only access `const` members. The object itself is still constructible, and must be destructible as well. That you're doing this *dynamically* is really the only difference. Edit:  pretty sure [this is a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755196/deleting-a-pointer-to-const-t-const) of your question.

Answer (score 5):

You are right. Normally, `const int*` cannot be implicitly converted into `void*` (in order to respect the const-correctness).

However, from the standard *[expr.delete]*:

> [ Note: A pointer to a const type can be the operand of a delete-expression; it is not necessary to cast away the constness of the pointer expression before it is used as the operand of the delete-expression.
>   — end note
>    ]

In order words, the *expression* `delete expr` is automatically handled by the compiler regarding the *const-correctness*.

Different story, for example, if you try to directly call the function, such as:

```
::operator delete(p);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Could you please explain more about how the compiler "handle `const` qualifier" ? Just discard it as a special case? Or there is some priority mechanism between `delete` and `const`?

Comment: `const` attribute is just an artificial construct parsed by the compiler. In the case of `delete` expression, the compiler just ignore the `const`.